# how to create a new column in postgresql UDR database

Tags: postgresql, ddl, postgresql-bdr

I need to be able to create a new column in an existing table in a database that has been set up to use postgresql UDR.
From what I've read, you cannot run DDL commands in BDR unless you write the syntax in a specific way...
For example, I found this post on stackoverflow:

[Django 1.8 Migration with Postgres BDR 9.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748630/django-1-8-migration-with-postgres-bdr-9-4-1)

I've tried to follow something similar with my UDR setup... but it's not working for me.

Specifically, I've tried the following:

```
mydatabase=# alter table mytable add column newcolumn character varying(50) not null default 'boo';
ERROR:  ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ... DEFAULT may only affect UNLOGGED or TEMPORARY tables when BDR is active; mytable is a regular table
```

and this:

```
mydatabase=# alter table mytable add column newcolumn character varying(50);
ERROR:  No peer nodes or peer node count unknown, cannot acquire DDL lock
HINT:  BDR is probably still starting up, wait a while
mydatabase=#
```

Are you allowed to run DDL commands in a UDR setup?
If anyone has some tips, I'd appreciate it.
thanks.

Comment: What is Postgres **UDR**? I know BDR, but not UDR

Comment: replication from a master to a slave.  uni-directional vs. bi-directional

Comment: So you mean a "standard" streaming replication setup (the built-in replication)? Yes, you can run *any* DDL statement on the master there

Comment: except it's using postgresql bdr to do it.  you can set postgresql-bdr package to do either bdr or udr.  if it can do it, would you mind posting some details re: how / where you think i've gone astray?  btw. i'm just taking over an existing db set up by my predecessor.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/a/a8/Udr-pgconf.pdf

Comment: and also http://bdr-project.org/docs/0.9.0/functions-node-mgmt.html fwiw.  Both links make reference to UDR

Comment: As it says in that PDF, you need to run DDL via `bdr_replicate_ddl_command()`.

Comment: yeah. i missed that the first time.  but after posting my comment with the link, i noticed it ... going to try it out this morning

Comment: omg u have 420 reputation. u r a god. pls no one up vote or downvote this user's questions